# LibSerial C++ Code does not run without Cutecom

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, libserial

I am trying to communicate through serial from Ubuntu 12.04 on to an ATxmega board using libserial. The problem that I am having is that my code does not run unless I run cutecom first. Unless I run cutecom first my program just freezes and does not output anything. I have tried several things like giving me sudo access to ttyUSB0, adding my user to the dialog group. Running it as su. I also tried adding the VTime and VMin but no luck neither.Here is my code which the program does not leave, it seems to never go into the while(ros::ok()) loop. I am using ros, but it should have no effect here. I am trying to communicate back and forth with the board at 1/10th of a second rate.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"

#include <SerialStream.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace LibSerial;

SerialStream mySerial;

void processSonar(char read[]);
char motor[] = {'s','3','6','0','0'};
unsigned int writeServo = 3600;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "mySerial");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    std::string serial = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
    mySerial.Open(serial);  
    mySerial.SetBaudRate( SerialStreamBuf::BAUD_57600 );
    mySerial.SetCharSize( SerialStreamBuf::CHAR_SIZE_8 );
    mySerial.SetNumOfStopBits( 1 );
    mySerial.SetParity( SerialStreamBuf::PARITY_NONE );
    mySerial.SetFlowControl( SerialStreamBuf::FLOW_CONTROL_NONE );
    mySerial.SetVTime( 1 );
    mySerial.SetVMin( 60 );

    while(!mySerial.IsOpen()){
        mySerial.Open(serial);  
        std::cout << "trying to open port" << std::endl;
        usleep(100000);
    }

//      if(!mySerial.good()){
//      std::cerr   << "Serial not Good"
//              << std::endl;
//      exit(1);
//      }

    char read[12];
    char* SerialP = read;
    char* motorP = motor;

    while(ros::ok())
    {
        mySerial.write(motorP, sizeof(motor));

        if(mySerial.rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0)
        {
            mySerial.read(SerialP, sizeof(read));
            std::cout << read << std::endl;
            processSonar(read);
            //std::cout << motor << writeServo << std::endl;
        }

        usleep(100000);
    }

    std::cout << "Communication Failure"<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It is not really my code. It was that for some reason modemmanager was getting on the way. I had to `sudo apt-get remove modemmanager` and then just give me permanent permission to dialout group by `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`. Restart and works like a charm. Hope this helps somebody.